# Vortex fog vortex gateway integration

Tags: iot, data-distribution-service, opensplice

I am new to Data Distributive Service.I am using PrismTech products for DDS.  I have vortex lite in my network. To interact with the vortex gateway in public cloud , i am using vortex fog service. But was not able to establish interaction. Can any one please provide input for the same.

I have a DDS subsystem running on my network , data from it needs to be shared to the vortex gateway running in the cloud, for this purpose i am try to use Vortex fog . IN vortex fog configuration i have mentioned the public ip of the cloud server. I have a vortex gateway subscriber job running in the cloud to receive the dds data from the subsystem running in my network.

Fog service is running in the LAN behind the NAT . I had set below configurations for running fog service

```
fog.cluster.id=LAN1
fog.user.network.interface=eth1
fog.routing.network.interface=eth1
fog.services.network.interface=eth1
fog.services.tcp.peers=<public ip of cloud server>:7400
fog.externalNetworkAddresses=none
```

In cloud server i am running the vortex gateway subscribing to different topics.

Could you please correct/guide me to solve this issue

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to give you a concrete answer as I don't have the details of your configuration. That said, let me try to give you some hint that may guide you toward the resolution of your problem.

1. Are there any applications subscribing for data on the Cloud? Notice that in Vortex data only flows if there is an interest arising. Otherwise no data is sent across the network -- that would just be a waste of precious resources. Beware that even if you have applications sharing data within a **Fog** but no applications subscribing to data "outside" the **Fog**, data won't be pushed out by Vortex-Fog. Once again, data flows only where there is an interest.
2. I assume that you are using Fog because you have an entire sub-system, i.e. several DDS applications, whose data needs to be efficiently shared with the cloud while maintaining multicast communication on the sub-system. If this is not the case, then you can simply configure Lite and the Gateway to use TCP/IP and have them talk directly. That would probably be the simplest deployment.
3. To ensure that you don't have any specific problems with your network set-up have you tried to run two Lite applications that use TCP/IP and communicate through our public Vortex Cloud instance available at demo-eu.prismtech.com or demo-us.prismtech.com?

If you post your configuration files I may be able to give you more insights.

HTH.

A+

Comment: As you mentioned i have a subsystem , data from it needs to be shared to the vortex gateway running on the cloud, for this purpose i am try to use Vortex fog . IN vortex fog configuration i have mentioned the public ip of the cloud server. I have a vortex gateway subscriber job running in the cloud to receiive the dds data from the subsystem running in my newtwork

Comment: Fog service is running in the LAN behind the NAT . I had set below configurations for running fog service

    fog.cluster.id=LAN1  
    fog.user.network.interface=eth1  
    fog.routing.network.interface=eth1         fog.services.network.interface=eth1  
    fog.services.tcp.peers=<public ip of cloud server>:7400  
    fog.externalNetworkAddresses=none  

In cloud server i am running the vortex gateway subscribing to different topics.

Comment: to ensure if its a problem with network  we tried to run two lite applications using tcp/ip communicate through  public Vortex Cloud instance  demo-eu.prismtech.com but still no communication occured.  COnfiguration file lite.xml file for vortex lite was configured as below. Could you please check and guide us

Comment: <DDSI2E>
<Tracing>
<PacketCaptureFile>ddsi.pcap</PacketCaptureFile>
<Verbosity>finest</Verbosity>
</Tracing>
<TCP>
<Enable>true</Enable>
<Port>7400</Port>
</TCP>
<Discovery>
<Peers>
<Peer address="demo-us.prismtech.com:7400"></Peer>
</Peers>
</Discovery>
<General>
<NetworkInterfaceAddress>auto</NetworkInterfaceAddress>
<AllowMulticast>false</AllowMulticast>
<EnableMulticastLoopback>false</EnableMulticastLoopback>
<EnableLoopback>false</EnableLoopback>
</General>
<Compatibility>
<StandardsConformance>lax</StandardsConformance>
</Compatibility>
</DDSI2E>